# How to tracing script flow

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell and have written some pretty large scripts ie a script that calls others scripts which have functions nested in other functions.  When I launch this script I sometimes get errors that I don't know where they came from.  Is there an easy way to see where this script terminated so I can troubleshoot the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Set-PsDebug` to get PowerShell to output almost every line it runs:

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1;
```

Only downside is you'll probably end up with a lot of output to wade through...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  However, I do see the big advantage in figuring out how to properly debug so I will look into that at a later time.

Answer (score 4):

For debugging to see where your error's are coming from I suggest debugging with the ISE or with PowerGUI.

You can also get a transcript of you script using the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet which will write all console activity to file. So you can put statements such as `Write-Host "Doing XYZ"`  and those will show up in the transcript log.

If you catch exceptions with a try catch or use a trap you can write the line number and column of the exception like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

trap {
  Write-Host "Error on line $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"
  exit 1
}

try {
    Get-Item DoesntExist
} catch {
    Write-Host ("Error occurred on line: " + $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)
}
```

`$_.InvocationInfo` has other details about were the error is coming from.

By setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` you ensure that any error triggers the `trap{}` block, which in this case writes out the line the script got to and exits.

Comment: Added more about the `trap{}` handling of errors, since this enables general troubleshooting of any error without needing to put `try{} catch{}` around too many statements.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the error includes the calling script.

Failing that you could try running the script ofr the Window PowerShell ISE in debug mode. This allows you to use break points and step through code.

Artile on using the ISE for debugging:

[ISE debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/19/debugging-powershell-script-using-the-ise-editor.aspx)

regards
Arcass